# upgrade to 22.04 broke sticky keys in a weirdly specific way, help?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I upgraded to 22.04 a few days ago, from 20.04, and now any two of the three things listed below work together fine, but not all three together (and I do need all three together to live, and they used to):

(1) sticky keys;

(2) the Polish keyboard layout (PL);

(3) right alt (left alt is fine).

Dell "Vostro 3580" and I'm afraid I'd need any explanation or instruction to be broken up into small steps. Thank you!

Edited:

Specifically. Sticky Keys are on,, the selected keyboard layout is PL, I'm in libreoffice writer or calc or gedit or anywhere in a browser where I can type. I expect rt-alt + S, for example, to type "ś", and I expect to get that result by hitting rt-alt first and hitting S next, without the finger acrobatics of holding rt-alt down while hitting S (which I can do, as you can see, but barely and with lots of effort). Instead, "s" is typed.

(But rt-alt still works, accesses menus for example, combined with sticky keys, but only when some other keyboard is selected, say EN; and even when PL is selected, sticky keys works, but only with shift, control and lt-alt, just not rt-alt.)

Comment: what, specifically, "doesn't work"? What do you do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: edited to make it more specific.

Comment: does rt-alt work if you aren't relying on sticky keys (press rt-alt and S at the same time)?

Comment: also are you using wayland or xorg?

Comment: possibly also some keyboard shortcut is interfering, check if there is a keyboard shortcut using GrAlt (right-alt) + some letter

Comment: Thank you. Wayland it says. Yes, when I'm not relying on sticky keys and press rt-alt and S at the same time, the expected things happens: "ś" if the keyboard is PL. No shortcut in system keyboard setting looks suspicious. rt-alt-S is just an example, it's rt-alt with ASEZXCNOL actually (ąśężźćńół, and the capitals when the rt-alt is combined with shift). In programs there might be interfering shortcuts, but not all of these everywhere. Certainly libreoffice always co-operated.